# Unable to install Wine ("sudo dpkg --configure -a")

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, wine, games

I would like to install an old game compatible only with Windows. By asking around, I found out that there is an application called Wine that allows you to install and launch "Windows" apps.
My problem is that I can't install this application.
When I try to install Wine through Ubuntu-Software or through the terminal, the result is the same, the installation stops and the following message appears: dpkg has been interrupted. It is necessary to use "sudo dpkg --configure -a" to correct the problem."
For more detail, here is the result I get when I try to install Wine with the terminal:

```
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
[sudo] Mot de passe de martin : 
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ sudo apt update
Atteint :1 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
Atteint :2 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease         
Atteint :3 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                  
Atteint :4 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Atteint :5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease          
Atteint :6 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease       
Atteint :7 https://deb.librewolf.net jammy InRelease                           
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
Tous les paquets sont à jour.
W: http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in            legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-  key(8) for details.
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key |   sudo apt-key add -
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-   key(8)).
OK
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
E: dpkg a été interrompu. Il est nécessaire d'utiliser « sudo dpkg --configure -a »   pour corriger le problème.
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-  builds/ubuntu/ $(lsb_release -cs) main"
Dépôt : « deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ jammy main »
Description :
Archive for codename: jammy components: main
Plus d'informations : http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
Ajout du dépôt.
Appuyez sur [ENTRÉE] pour continuer ou Ctrl-c pour annuler
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-   http_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-http_dl_winehq_org_wine- builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri- http_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri- http_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list
Atteint :1 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease
Atteint :2 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Atteint :3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease         
Atteint :4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease          
Atteint :5 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease       
Atteint :6 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Atteint :7 https://deb.librewolf.net jammy InRelease                           
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait            
W: http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in   legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-  key(8) for details.
martin@martin-Latitude-E5520:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
E: dpkg a été interrompu. Il est nécessaire d'utiliser « sudo dpkg --configure -a »   pour corriger le problème.
```

(This way to install Wine 6.0 comes from this site: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-instal ... tu-20-04/)

Here I thank the brave ones for having arrived here! How can I solve this problem and what is this command "sudo dpkg --configure -a"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use any instructions you found on the internet to install wine. Unless you have a specific known need for a particular wine version, undo everything you have done and install the version of wine that is already in the jammy repos.

Comment: I tried to install Wine with the command line "sudo apt install wine" and it seems to have worked fine.
I say "looks like" because during the installation via the terminal everything worked but the only problem is that I can't find the Wine application. More precisely, it doesn't appear in my applications menu nor when I go to the settings and look in the "applications" menu...
On the other hand, I found a trace of Wine in the /bin folder but I don't know how to use it...

Comment: Good news that you got it installed! There is no gui for wine itself. You can type `winecfg` in a terminal and that will give you a small gui interface that will confirm that it's working. Click on the `about` tab to see the version you ended up with. wine can be frustratingly difficult to use but it's a great tool for those of us who switched over from Windows and need to still run a few programs.

Comment: As the output tells you, you need to run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix the issue.

Comment: Before you even started did you go to the Wine support site to see if the app you want to use works with Wine or has any special needs. It seems you have the wrong idea about what Wine can do it only runs SOME Windows apps. Go to this site and look https://appdb.winehq.org/